# opening javascript popup from multiple windows does not return values to correct window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 3 windows/pages.

Page1 is a basic webpage that when a button is clicked it opens up a popup window via javascript

Page2 is similar to page one, it just is on a different page.

Page3 (aka the popup) is the actual popup window that Page1 and Page2 can open.

Page1 and Page2 use similar javascript to open the popup (Page3). The javascript looks like this...

```
    function openPopup() {

        popupwindow = window.open(Page3Url, title, options, true);
        popupwindow.focus();

        var unloadFunc = function () {
                self.focus();                  
                $('#txtBox').val(popupwindow.$('#SomeTextBoxValueINeed').val());
            }
        };

        popupwindow.attachEvent('onbeforeunload', unloadFunc);                         
    }
```

I should also mention that the popup (Page3) has a submit button that will postback to the server and inject some window.close() javascript into the ScriptManager to close the page.

If I open the popup from Page1 and submit the popup my 'unloadFunc' gets called and everything works great.

Same holds true for opening Page3 from Page2.

The Problem is if I open up the popup from Page1 and DO NOT close the popup THEN I open up the popup from Page2, the popup will get refreshed just fine, but when I submit the popup my unloadFunc does not get called and I have no idea why. Any ideas anyone?!

Thanks in advance! Any help would be appreciated!