# Closing a popup window from a window the popup was not opened in using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I open a popup from a page is there a way I can close that popup from a different page?

Page1->Creates and opens popup.

Page2->Closes popup.

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample code and shared more about what you have tried or researched so far.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can not keep a reference to your popup window on navigation, no you can not do this. But if you use `pushState` to change the url of your parent window and do not actually navigate, you can do it. Just simply by using `close()` method you can close that popup window

Other option is using a server side script to send the close signal to you popup window

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried explaining my dilemma in this post but haven't received any answers. It's a tad wordy and confusing. Really hard to describe my situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369922/opening-javascript-popup-from-multiple-windows-does-not-return-values-to-correct

Answer (score 1):

I think any well-coded browser should run each page in a sandboxed environment, so one page should not even be aware that other pages exist or are being browsed, let alone what they do to the DOM or the javascript they run.

Therefore, any solution to allow communication from two different webpages (or the same page loaded two times in the browser), would have to go via an external mechanism. If its the same page loaded two times within the same browser, they should share their `localStorage`, so you could use it as a way to send messages.

If not, you can always rely on an external web service to do this. The page opening the popup would have to implement a polling service to see whether it should close it, and the page attempting to close the popup would have to make an AJAX call requesting it to the server, and wait for the other page to pull the result.

It's not as easy as one line of javascript, but if you **REALLY** want this feature, you could implement it.